# No available provider "azure" plugins are compatible with this Terraform version. Azurerm -1.28 Terraform -

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

My environment looks like the following on OSX.

NJ033-10126375:old-example 10126375$ terraform version
Terraform v0.12.10
+ provider.azurerm v1.28.0
+ provider.random v2.2.1

**edit:** when i run `terraform providers` i get the following

```
.
├── provider.azure
├── provider.azurerm ~>1.35
└── provider.random
```

I get the following error in terraform.

```
No available provider "azure" plugins are compatible with this 

Terraform version.

From time to time, new Terraform major releases can change the requirements for
plugins such that older plugins become incompatible.

Terraform checked all of the plugin versions matching the given constraint:
    (any version)

Unfortunately, none of the suitable versions are compatible with this version
of Terraform. If you have recently upgraded Terraform, it may be necessary to
move to a newer major release of this provider. Alternatively, if you are
attempting to upgrade the provider to a new major version you may need to
also upgrade Terraform to support the new version.

Consult the documentation for this provider for more information on
compatibility between provider versions and Terraform versions.
```

Below is my vars.auto.tfvars (changing the version or omitting it doesn't help)

```
variable subscription_id {}
variable tenant_id {}
variable client_id {}
variable client_secret {}

provider "azurerm" {
   subscription_id = "${var.subscription_id}"
   tenant_id = "${var.tenant_id}"
   client_id = "${var.client_id}"
   client_secret = "${var.client_secret}"
   version = "=1.28.0"
}
```

Here is what is even more interesting, this code was working a few days ago i try to run it again with no changes and its broken. I then use brew upgrade terraform and then other projects that were working no longer work.

Pretty much I cant get past a terraform init.

**Issue solved** it was due to a typo of using **azure_public_ip** instead of **azurerm_public_ip**.

Comment: I solved my same issue by using azurerm_ prefix too. but why does it give a misleading error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the AzureRM Terraform provider supports 0.12.x until 1.29.  Change your provider version constraint to:

```
version = "~>1.35"
```

This will get you the latest version and it will also be able to go up from there. Here is the link to the AzureRM provider change log.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Hey Scott how did you find this out, is it on a github page somewhere? I was having trouble trying to figure out which version goes with which.

Comment: @FrankVisaggio - Added a link to my answer.  Github is your friend!!  I would also say that hard coding to a specific provider version ("==1.28.0") is probably not necessary.  Major versions will likely cause major breaks, but minors should be ok.  Using what I put in the answer will make sure you get updates.

Comment: I still get a similar error and if i look it seems to be complaining about the Azure version not azure RM. edited my original post to show what terraform providers shows.

Comment: I don't see any provider named "azure".  Can you share all of your code?

Comment: figured it out i had a silly typo in the resource of saying "azure_public_ip" instead of "azurerm_public_ip"